# Unable to use jquery.html() with ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem when trying to select the `<li>` inside a `<ul>` list from an ajax response using `jQuery.html();`

This is my AJAX request:

```
if (searchid != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/service/search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false
            }).done(function (html) {
                $("#result").html(html).show();
                var images = $("#result").find(".dbRows.sixth").html();
                console.debug(images);
            })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    $("#explainMessage").html('Unable to check at the moment. Please retry later').show();
                })
        }
        return false;
```

and in php I have this code:

```
if ( mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) 
  {
        $display = '<div id="explainMessage" class="explainMessage">Sorry, this was not found.</div>';
        echo $display;
    } else {
        $counter = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ++$counter;
              $image_filename = $row['image_filename'];

     $imageFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/service/img/';
            $imageList = scandir($imageFolder, 1);
            $imageLink = '/service/img/' . $image_filename;
            $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $image_filename);
            $pattern = '/^(' . quotemeta($withoutExt) . ').*$/';

     $display = '<div class="dbRows sixth" style="display:none"><ul>';
                foreach ($imageList as $image) {
                    if (preg_match($pattern, $image)) {
                        if (in_array($image, $imageList)) {
                            $display .= '<li><img src="' . $imageLink . '" /></li>';
                        }
                    }
                };
                $display .= '</ul></div>';
             echo $display;
```

the problem is that when I try to use the `AJAX.done();` function, in my console I have just `<ul></ul>` without the list of images.My question is, why i can't select the code inside the `<ul>` tags even if the list of images is actually in the code? I'm pretty new with PHP, any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not getting any HTML in the console, chances are the PHP doesn't output any. Are you sure `$imageList` contains anything and that the if conditions are true

Comment: Where did the `$imageLink` in `$display .= '<li><img src="' . $imageLink . '" /></li>';` come from?

Comment: sorry that was not clear, #results.html works, is just the var images that doesn't take the inner html from this line of code => $("#result").find(".dbRows.sixth").html();  and that print in the console just an empty list

Comment: @AfaanBilal edited with more php code.

Comment: Now where did the `$image_filename` come from? Can you please post the complete code?

Comment: @AfaanBilal it cames from a db. All the DB code and request works fine as everything is displayed properly in the code. I think it is more a jquery issue rather than a php one. Edited anyway.

Comment: Can you post whatever you see in network response tab? It will help us people to dig in correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. As I doubt before asking you for response HTML, you have blank `'.

`$("#result").find(".dbRows.sixth").html()` will print html for first matched element only.

Try this, if you want to fetch html for all matched element:

```
$("#result").find(".dbRows.sixth").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look I can see a few problems. In your php change your first line of code from `<div class="dbRows sixth" style="display:none"><ul>';` to `$display = '<div class="dbRows sixth" style="display:none"><ul>';`

I'd probably change this: `var images = $("#result").find(".dbRows.sixth").html();` to this: `var images = $("#result > .dbRows.sixth");`.

Then add `images.show();` and `console.log(images.html());`. Not tested but might get you on the right track.

Comment: I've made the changed you suggested, but in the console i have just undefined.

Comment: In your done function if you output `html` to your console what do you see? Is the html there?

Comment: yes, it is. It's displayed properly and also inside the div. Is just that bit of code that doesn't work. can it be that when the var is created the list is still empty because the images are not there yet? at least i think that it could be something similar to this problem maybe..but not sure. And also, the same class dbRows.sixth is present more than once, and some of this could be empty. Not sure if this helps

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your php loop. So the html for `.dbRows.sixth` is `<div class="dbRows sixth" style="display:none"><ul></ul></div></div></div></div><div class="results compatibility-1" id="dbResults">`.  You've got a list with no list items in it.

Comment: I've posted the network response in my original answer and actually the lists are not empty. The <li> is actually present in the code...